# Android Overflow menu works appears perfectly in Android Studio preview but does not show up on actual device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am trying to add an overflow menu (the three dots) to my Android app.
It appears perfectly on preview (Android Studio) but fails to show up on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 tablet. why?

Here is what I did so far:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.boci.helloworldandroidgithub" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</resources>
```

**styles.xml(v21)**

```
<resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:enabled="true" >

        <item android:id="@+id/main_red"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_red">
        </item>

        <item android:id="@+id/main_green"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_green">
        </item>

        <item android:id="@+id/main_blue"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:title="@string/menu_blue">
        </item>

    </group>

</menu>
```

What else should I configure if I would like to see those three dots and options?

Answer (score 0):

The overflow button is not shown because of this code in [ActionBarPolicy](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/e3bbb6a575d60e382e2c7882803be078db983d21/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/view/ActionBarPolicy.java#L49-L55):

```
public boolean showsOverflowMenuButton() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return !ViewConfigurationCompat.hasPermanentMenuKey(ViewConfiguration.get(mContext));
    }
}
```

As you can see if the device is lower of KitKat the overflow button is not displayed if the device has an hardware key.

You can override this settings adding this code in the `onCreate` method of your `Activity`:

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: That sounds completely logical and I wold love to accept as the correct answer. The only problem is however, that I am still unable to see those three bloody dots:-( (or anything on the actionbar)